# CDI in Desktop Application

Tags: java, cdi

I'm creating a JAR that can be use by WEB or DESKTOP application. This JAR should have some classes with @RequestScoped and others CDI annotations, so i have some doubts about it:

1) I understand that @RequestScoped is just for HTTP REQUEST, but how can i use this in a Desktop Application ? It's possible ?
2) I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

But this dependency is just for weld for WEB, i need some more generic that should work in WEB or DESKTOP.

If i use "weld-se" as dependency my JAR wil work only for DESKTOP, i don't want to this.

Comment: There's rarely a case where you need the same jar to be portable on both platforms. Create 2 jars.

Comment: Imagine this is a framework. I can use in a DESKTOP project or a WEB project. How can i give the choose of wich WELD use to this "Child Project".

Comment: You see... WELD is a framework too, and they have separate jars for both platforms.

Comment: Ok.I will check this, but another thing: How CDI understand ApplicationScoped and SessionScoped in JAVA SE, if this don't have Session in JAVA SE.

Comment: Btw had you tried to add both dependencies at once? If they use different package schemes, they shouldn't conflict. You should be able to annotate your classes with both types at once.

Comment: How do you run your web applications? Tomcat? Wildfly?

Comment: They dont use different package schemes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was said by user MouseEvent in the comment, it is usually better to have two separate JARs for this.

However, what I aim to answer is your question about `@RequestScoped` beans in non-web environment (and also `@Session` and `@Application`). So let's say we are using **Weld in SE environment - now, what works and what doesn't?**

- `@ApplicationScoped` **works just fine** and as you would expect. One bean per application. It's lifecycle starts when you boot container and stops when you shut it down. An alternative to this is usage of `@javax.inject.Singleton` (note that this is [CDI singleton](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_the_singleton_pseudo_scope), not EJB) beans, but that should be limited to SE only - this behaves equally to application scoped bean but has no proxy created. This might give you the upper hand in some cases but also prevents things like serialization.
- `@SessionScoped` at the moment **does not work in SE** environment as it does not really make any sense there. As you said yourself, you have no session there.
- `@RequestScoped` **does work in SE**. This makes sense as "request" can mean more things than just plain old HTTP request. However, you will need to take care of activation of this scope. While there are several ways (such as extending the context and handling activation yourself) I would advise to use an annotation (interceptor binding in fact) provided in Weld API - [`@ActivateRequestContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_request_context). You simply put the annotation on top of your method and Weld will activate the request context before the method starts and shut it down afterwards. You can also put this on whole class which means it will work for every method. Note that you will need have dependency on Weld API to gain access to this annotation (or you need to use CDI 2.0 where this [was added as well](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0.Beta1/cdi-spec.html#activating_request_context)).

As for your dependency, in SE environment, you will want this one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So, in Java SE to active RequestSCoped i need add ActivateRequestCOntext ? Just call method don't active this ?

Comment: You just add the interceptor binding above the method which needs to have request context active. Say that you have a method `public void doWork() {..}` then you will simply add `@ActivateRequestContext` above the method and Weld will do the rest for you.

So in the end you end up having `@ActivateRequestContext public void doWork() {..}`. Similarly you can add it to your whole bean class and have request context activated/deactivated for all methods within that class.

Comment: I'm thinking about create a myjar-core-se and don't use CDI, because i don't see any advantage in use CDI inside on JAVA SE. DO you agree ? (After i will create myjar-core to web project)

Comment: I was thinking use this structure: myjar-core, myjar-web (use myjar-core) and myjar-desktop (use myjar-core). But as i see won't work

Comment: I am not sure I can see what exactly are you trying to achieve. But I think that Weld/CDI in SE makes sense and if often worth it. It still gives you the upper hand by having a container which manages lifecycles of your components (+events, interceptors,...). Furthermore, in theory, you should be able to use SE container even in servlets but this will probably give you headaches. You would need to do many context-related things manually. That being said I think you can still define CDI beans in your `myjar-core` (or even more than that) and later on use the, from either SE or web app.

Comment: If you add `my-core.jar` as a dependency your SE/web app will be able to pick up CDI beans/interceptors etc. you can go even further with extension I believe. It really depends on your architecture and what would be inside core jar (if it is worth it).

Comment: But in myjar-core i have beans with SessionScoped and others with Request Scope

Comment: As I explained, `@SessionScoped` beans do not make any sense in SE applications, you should re-think the way you design the application.

Comment: But i can use RequestScope in SE and Webapp ? Because in weld official page only ApplicationScoped, Dependent and Singleton are supported

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133474/discussion-between-scientist-and-siliarus).